# Как ограничить доступ к проекту/порту в Docker?

Tags: docker, debian, docker-compose, iptables, ufw

Мне необходимо ограничить доступ к некоторым портам по IP адресу (закрыть для всех, кроме X). Ранее проекты лежали на сервере Debian и использовали веб-сервер Nginx, что позволяло использовать `iptables` или же `ufw` для контроля доступа. В Docker это невозможно, так как он игнорирует настройки основной машины и использует свои.

В интернете прочитал, что можно установить `iptables` в контейнер для Nginx, выглядит это следующим образом:

```
iptables -I DOCKER-USER 2 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport [порт] -s [IP из белого списка] -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport [порт] -j DROP
```

В таком случаи, чтобы я не делал всё время получаю ошибку, которая говорит о том, что у Docker нет прав на использование `iptables`. Как я могу ограничить доступ к порту в Docker?

Comment: Какое отношение команды выше имеют к Nginx? В любом случае, почитай доки https://docs.docker.com/network/packet-filtering-firewalls/#restrict-connections-to-the-docker-host
`DROP` надо в цепочку `DOCKER-USER` добавлять, а не в `INPUT`